# How can there be concentration and pressure terms simultaneously in the Nernst equation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

In the Nernst equation we are taught that the reaction quotient can have pressure terms and concentration terms simultaneously. According to my knowledge this does not happen anywhere else, so why can it happen here?

Comment: Look up “Hypochlorite” in wiki: the first equilibrium expression shows it happens. There are many, many more as well. The acidified hypochlorite equilibrium, by the way, is why some careless people gas themselves when they try to clean their toilets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic often causes confusion.

The most correct form of the Nernst equation uses [thermodynamic activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_activity) of the substances:

$$E = E^{\circ} - \frac{RT}{zF} \ln\frac{a_\mathrm{red}}{a_\mathrm{ox}}$$

For diluted solutions, we can replace the activity of a substance with its concentration in the solution. But how do we express the activity of a gas?

This is basically the question of how to formulate the equilibrium constant of the redox reaction. There are actually **multiple solutions to this**. The problem is that all of them are correct.

**Solution 1**: Express activity of the gas as a function of partial pressure.
\begin{align}
pV &= nRT \\
\Rightarrow p &= \frac{n}{V}RT = cRT\\
a(\mathrm{gas}) &\approx c(\mathrm{gas}) = \frac{p(\mathrm{gas})}{RT}
\end{align}

**Solution 2**: Just use the partial pressure itself:
$$a(\mathrm{gas}) = p(\mathrm{gas})$$

**Solution 3**: Use the partial pressure divided by a reference pressure:
$$a(\mathrm{gas}) = \frac{p(\mathrm{gas})}{p(\mathrm{reference})}$$

Comment: I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). Especially `\rm` will introduce unwanted side effects. Solution 1 & 2 do not conserve the unit of $a$.

Comment: You should explain how to get rid of the units, because the logarithm of a number has only a sense if this number has no units. The log of a pressure has only a sense when it is divided by a reference pressure. Which sort of reference do you recommend ?

Comment: I don't agree with solution 1. What about the concentration of the dissolved gas? If the reaction is between a gas and a compound in solutions, then it's the gas dissolved in solution that matters not it's concentration in air.